# Why is there no HTMLSectionElement and no HTMLArticleElement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

You can test whether an element is a `div` or a `span` like this:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
console.log(div instanceof HTMLDivElement);

const span = document.createElement('span');
console.log(span instanceof HTMLSpanElement);
```

This way of testing so far has worked for *most* HTML elements I'm aware of.

Unfortunately, the same approach of checking an element type is not available for `section` and `article`  elements, which would mean I'd probably have to resort to `el.tagName === 'SECTION'` respectively `el.tagName === 'ARTICLE'`.

Edit: Just tested, the following globals **all don't exist either**:

- `HTMLNavElement`
- `HTMLHeaderElement`
- `HTMLMainElement`
- `HTMLAsideElement`
- `HTMLFooterElement`

Does anyone know, and have any reference, as of why there are no `HTMLSectionElement` and `HTMLArticleElement` globals?

Is this because all of them are technically `div` elements with a different tag name to provide better semantics?

Comment: You'll notice these are all HTML5 elements

Comment: This isn't really about JavaScript. It's about the W3C DOM spec.

Comment: take alook at this [HTML: 1.6.5. Object definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-798055546)

Comment: @Pointy Added the [tag:dom] tag.

Comment: Also section 3.2.2 of the HTML5 DOM spec. I think that's the "smoking gun" in the spec. Any element that doesn't need more than what the base interface provides should use plain HTMLElement.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman The current specification is on [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html). Your link points to an 18 year old specification.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman That looks like a good starting point *"Elements that only expose the HTML core attributes are represented by the base HTMLElement interface."* Unfortunately it is part of DOM level 2 spec and lists none of the tags I mentioned. I assume the quoted statement stays true for those as well.

Comment: @Pointy Added your comment as an answer for future readers. If you want the reputation, feel free to add an answer and I will delete mine and pick yours.

Comment: Connexo , @SebastianSimon ,  u r totally true i haven't noticed this, as long as it's DOM level 2 old stuff

Comment: The question could also be, why is there an `HTMLSpanElement` interface which has no properties, other than the inherited ones, but no `HTMLSectionElement` interface. I believe the answer to that is the good old “Because that’s what has historically happened and the ancient spec says so, and we can’t change it because web compat”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @pointy for his comment pointing this out, the following [section of the current HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#elements-in-the-dom) explains this:

> The basic interface, from which all the HTML elements' interfaces inherit, and which **must be used by elements that have no additional requirements**, is the `HTMLElement` interface.

Comment: And note that `<div>` for example has its own interface to support the deprecated "align" property, and I think no other reason.

Comment: @Pointy - But as a counter example, `<span>` has no additional properties, obsolete/deprecated or not, but its interface is [HTMLSpanElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#htmlspanelement)

Comment: @Alohci yes but it also predates HTML5.

Comment: @Pointy - [HTMLPictureElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#htmlpictureelement)

Comment: All I can tell you is what's written in the DOM spec as quoted by this answer.